# Sorting 2D PHP array naturally

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Okay, I'm officially going nuts. I have tried all solutions found online, however none is working.

I have this array:

```
$hits = array(
    array('sortby' => 'String 1', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 1</div>',
    array('sortby' => 'String 11', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 11</div>',
    array('sortby' => 'String 2', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 2</div>',
);
```

I want to sort the $hits array naturally by the "sortby" key, so the output becomes like this:

```
 <div>This element contains String 1</div>
 <div>This element contains String 2</div>
 <div>This element contains String 11</div>
```

Which sort function could I use?

Comment: You probably have to write your own function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `usort()`, with a `strnatcmp()` comparison.

```
$hits = array(
    array('sortby' => 'String 1', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 1</div>'),
    array('sortby' => 'String 11', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 11</div>'),
    array('sortby' => 'String 2', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 2</div>')
);

usort($hits, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['sortby'], $b['sortby']);
});

var_dump($hits);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sortby"]=>
    string(8) "String 1"
    ["html"]=>
    string(41) "<div>This element contains String 1</div>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sortby"]=>
    string(8) "String 2"
    ["html"]=>
    string(41) "<div>This element contains String 2</div>"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sortby"]=>
    string(9) "String 11"
    ["html"]=>
    string(42) "<div>This element contains String 11</div>"
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($hits, function($a, $b){
    return strnatcmp($a['sortby'], $b['sortby']);
});
```

- Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
- Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qqNpRl

Comment: as he wanted it naturally sorted: function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a['sortby'], $b['sortby']); }

Comment: It's definitely **not** naturally sorted: `11, 2, 473, 5` instead of `2, 5, 11, 473`

Comment: @JensSchulze I missed "naturally" part thanks for fix

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
<?php
$hits = array(
    array('sortby' => 'String 1', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 1</div>'),
    array('sortby' => 'String 11', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 11</div>'),
    array('sortby' => 'String 2', 'html' => '<div>This element contains String 2</div>')
);

function comp($a, $b) {
    $n1 = intval(substr($a['sortby'], 7));
    $n2 = intval(substr($b['sortby'], 7));
    return $n1>$n2;
}

usort($hits, "comp");

print_r($hits);

?>
```

Using `usort()`, you can apply your sort rule.